# Facebook Graph API: Publishing a link - OAuthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, facebook-wall

In my website, users can share links of my app "objects" to their Facebook Wall.

This is how I post links to Facebook using the Javascript SDK and their Graph API:

```
var url = "/me/feed";
var message = "a user generated message"
var link = "link to an internal object of my app"
FB.api(url, "post", { message: message, link: link }, callback);
```

These are some of the metatags of my internal objects:

```
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />
<meta property="og:video" content="link to an internal object of my app"/>
```

Whereas I don't attach any Flash content, I'm encountering this error:

```
error: (#100) flash objects must have the 'source' and 'picture' attributes
type: OAuthException
```

So there is something I don't really understand...

The weirdest thing is that when I post the same link from Facebook Web Interface (and not through my app), everything occurs seamlessly... Indeed: I don't have any warnings or errors from the Facebook Linter tool.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you have videos you should check at what nrj12 did for example (see here http://www.nrj12.fr/nrj12-replay-3276/nrj-12-562/media/video/494835-avec-rod-janois.html)

```
<meta content="Nrj 12 Avec rod janois - NRJ12.fr" property="og:title">
<meta content="http://www.nrj12.fr/nrj12-replay-3276/nrj-12-562/media/video/494835-avec-rod-janois.html" property="og:url">
<meta content="fr_FR" property="og:locale">
<meta content="video.tv_show" property="og:type">
<meta content="1327098374" property="video:release_date">
<meta content="169879703048651" property="fb:app_id">
<meta content="Sport auto, nouveautés, tests, exclusivités... KILOMETRE 12, c est le nouveau magazine indispensable présenté par Anne Denis pour tout savoir sur le monde de l auto. Mais c est aussi des rubriques déc..." property="og:description">
```

```
<meta content="223" property="og:video:height">
<meta content="398" property="og:video:width">
<meta content="application/x-shockwave-flash" property="og:video:type">
<meta content="http://media.nrj.fr/436x327/mogador/00152885-minipicto-12-0_prod_12229.jpg" property="og:image">
```

You video:type looks weird too me cause HTML is not a video type.

Please provide the URL of the content you wish to publish if you want to get constructive help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The type "text/html" is perfectly valid: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/ (see the videos paragraph). It's meant to redirect to the page of the video when you don't want your video to be embedded on Facebook. I'm sorry but I can't give you the URL (still in test). Thanks anyway!